# Proving area of triangle formed at parallelogram midpoint is 1/4 of the parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

ABCD is a parallelogram . X is the midpoint of AD & Y is the midpoint of BC. Show that the area of $\triangle {ABX}$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ the area of ABCD

[image]

Can you help me with this proof? Where should I start? I think It should be by proving

$\triangle{DBC} \cong \triangle{DBA} $ using SAS as DB is a common side DC= AB as ABCD is a parallelogram, $\angle {BDC} = \angle{DBA} $ alternate angles

And I can also predict that the use of the midpoint theorem here.

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: The point $Y$ is there for a reason - draw XY and YD and observe that you get four congruent triangles!

Comment: ok i updated the diagram , now what would be the case for congruency ?

Comment: The problem is solved by the diagram alone. This is called a _proof without words_ and they crop up often in geometry.

Comment: @user366082 All corresponding angles and sides having the same magnitude, due to properties of parallelograms.

Answer (score 4):

The length of perpendicular for the triangle and parallelogram is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $Y$ is the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$.

Use this to divide the parallelogram into four triangles and show that these are congruent.

Comment: Using what condition?

Comment: @user366082 It's a parallelogram.

Comment: what case like side angle side should be uesd?

Answer (score 3):

Observe $$ar(BAXY)=ar(DXYC)$$

[image]

Since $BAXY$ and $DXYC$ are also parallelograms and we know that the diagonal of a parallelogram divides it into two triangles of equal area.
$$ar(ABCD)=2\times\frac 12 ar(ABCD)$$ $$ar(ABCD)=ar(BAXY)+ar(DXYC)$$ $$ar(ABCD)=2\times \frac{1}{2}[ar(BAXY)+ar(DXYC)]$$ $$ar(ABCD)=2\times [ar(\triangle ABX)+ar(\triangle BXY)+ar(\triangle XYD)+ar(\triangle YDC)]$$ **$$ar(ABCD)=4\times ar(\triangle ABX)=4\times ar(\triangle BXY)=4\times ar(\triangle XYD)=4\times ar(\triangle YDC)$$**